# Bootstrap 3 popovers that work for others do not work for me

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Before commenting on this question, please read the next paragraph:

The following code was presented as the solution [to another question](http://t151.codeinpro.us/q/5081340a4f1eba38a42b4b0f), and I provide it here (after testing it myself) just as an example. I've tried numerous examples of supposedly working Twitter Bootstrap popover code, and none of it works *for me*. However, the Twitter Bootstrap tooltip code works just fine.

I cannot, for the life of me, see why this won't work.

[jsFiddle here (updated with new libraries)](http://jsfiddle.net/ybM5j/1/), and [someone else's here](http://jsfiddle.net/mT76T/18/)

Because the first two examples are essentially identical, here is a third that is supposed to work: http://jsfiddle.net/r1ch0/yPJ2F/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="blob" class="btn large primary" rel="popover" 
    data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging." 
    data-original-title="A title">hover for popover</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#blob").popover({
    offset: 10
});
```

I expect everyone to say that it works for them. My question is "Why won't it work for me?" I have all correct libraries loaded -- as you can tell from the jsFiddle examples. They work for you, but not for me.

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Both doesn't work for me in Chrome!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Looks like I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the External Resources that you are using in the jsFiddle, they are not correct...

[Remove them and add links from here](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Comment: Libraries updated per your recommendation. Still nothing. As mentioned previously, these examples worked for others but not for me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/ybM5j/2/ all i did was change the ext. resources and it works fine now...

Comment: Thanks Schmalzy, that's what I was getting at. Still doesn't work for me. But I'll replace my links above with this one, truly known to work.

Comment: Your updated examples don't work because you added the resources wrong.... just add the URL, not the entire <link> and <script> tags.

Comment: Also, your code is not set up to open the popover on hover as the button says, you have to click the button.

Comment: Good grief. <embarrassed>It's *that* simple?</embarrassed> That's all I needed to see: that a popover example actually works for me. Looks like I was just adding the library links incorrectly (I had tried that previous to making this posting, but obviously made the same mistake.) Thanks for putting me right!

Comment: No problem. http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/ybM5j/3/ See this one for opening on hover. I added the option `trigger: 'hover'` which makes it show on hover.

Comment: Very kind - exactly what I wanted. Thank you.